# My cpanel -FTP UPLOAD_OPRATION quota exceeded

Tags: cpanel

I Don't know what has happened to my cpanel `FTP.` I am unable to save and update anything. I have used many ftp clients.

**Error**:-`FTP UPLOAD_OPRATION quota exceeded`

[See This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbDNZ.jpg)

Comment: Shouldn't this be a question for your hosting provider?

Comment: Sorry but i can't talk to them right now☹️